# Openlayers Map is shown only if the CSS contains a syntax error

Tags: css, openlayers

I'm trying to create a webpage that shows an almost fullscreen map. The map should fill the space between header and footer. This is the code I have so far:

HTML:

```
<header>
    <div class="mainBodyElement" id="header">
    </div>
</header>

<div id="content">
    <div id="map"></div>
</div>

<footer>
    <div class="mainBodyElement" id="footer">
        <p>&copy; 2013</p>
    </div>
</footer>
```

Javascript:

```
var map;

function initOpenLayers() {
    /* Example code from openlayers.org */
    map = new OpenLayers.Map({
        div: "map",
        layers: [
        new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM("OSM (without buffer)"),
        new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM("OSM (with buffer)", null, {
            buffer: 2
        })],
        controls: [
        new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation({
            dragPanOptions: {
                enableKinetic: true
            }
        }),
        new OpenLayers.Control.PanZoom(),
        new OpenLayers.Control.Attribution()]
    });

    map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher());
    map.zoomToMaxExtent();
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    initOpenLayers();
});
```

CSS:

```
<!-- <> -->
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
.mainBodyElement {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#header {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #2CA07A;
    color: white;
}
#footer {
    top: auto;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 34px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #2CA07A;
    color: white;
}
#content {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 34px;
    overflow: auto;
    background: #EEE;
}
/* login
    ----------------------------------------------------------*/
#login {
    float: right;
    display: block;
    font-size: .85em;
    margin: 0 0 10px;
    text-align: right;
}
#login a {
    background-color: #d3dce0;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 3px;
    padding: 2px 3px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#login .email {
    background: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #CCCCCC;
}
#login ul {
    margin: 0;
}
#login li {
    display: inline;
    list-style: none;
}
#map {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

I've created a fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/palpitation/MUKRe/3/) which shows a working example (it'll fill when you zoom in which is alright), but it also shows my question:

The first line of the CSS is:

```
<!-- <> -->
```

This is invalid syntax because it's in a CSS block, but if I omit it, the map won't show. Even if I omit the `<>` part of this line only, the map won't show anymore. I'm at a loss and really don't know how to keep it working without this strange line of code. If I keep the line though, Visual Studio keeps bugging me about invalid syntax. I don't like to have invalid syntax to keep my code running, so I hope that someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `<!-- <> -->` is invalidating and causing your rules in the first set of curly brackets to break. This css,

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

along with your weird line of code should be removed, and everything should be fine. Specifically, it is the `* {overflow: hidden;}` which is the culprit.

Comment: I didn't know that only the first set of curly brackets would break in this case. This was indeed the answer. A big thank you for your very clear answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
overflow: hidden;
```

is the problem

Comment: Which is indeed the answer, but not very clear since there are more than one `overflow: hidden`s in the css.